# Create query for a child to use the parameters of the parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Could you help me please.
I searched the internet and could not find any solutions.
How create query for a child to use the parameters of the parent?

```
var Photos = new Schema({
    photo_id: {type: String, required: true},
    photo_path_low: { type: String, required: true }
});

var Users = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: String, required: true },
    count_coins: { type: Number, default: 20 },
    photos_relation: [Photos]
});
...
... some code
...
PhotoModel.findOne().where('parent.count_coins').gt(1)..... // parent for Example
```

Comment: Your Photo scheme does not have a reference to the User.

Comment: How to add a reference to the user? Give an example of, if not difficult.

Comment: Read docs it has everything you need

Comment: I could not find information about it in the docs. I look forward to advice.

Comment: If this is not possible, then tell me. How I can make query to obtain photos, influenced count_coins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case there are Object-references:

```
var Photos = new Schema({
    photo_id: {type: String, required: true},
    photo_path_low: { type: String, required: true }
    createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
});
```

Then, when you make your query, you can populate references like this:

```
Photo.findOne({_id: 123})
.populate('createdBy')
.exec(function(err, post) {
    // do stuff with post
});
```

You can find more in [this mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).